# If $x$ has odd order, then $x^i \neq x^{-i}$ for all $1 \leq i < n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

**Problem:** Assume that $x \in G$ and $|x| = n < \infty$. Prove that if $x$ has odd order, then $x^i  \neq x^{-i}$ for all $1 \leq i < n$.

**Attempt:** First note that $x^i = x^{-i}$ is equivalent to $x^{i} = (x^{i})^{-1}$ i.e we're thinking about whether a particular power of $x$ is it's own inverse. Suppose for contradiction that $x$ has odd order, but there exists some $k \in \{1,...,n-1\}$ satisfying $x^k = x^{-k}$. By the intuition above we know that it is it's own inverse and it follows that $x^kx^k = x^{2k}= 1$. Two possible cases;

1. The exponent $2k < n$. Here we directly get a contradiction because $|x| = n$.
2. The exponent $2k>n$. Here we may use the division algorithm to assert that there exist $b,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $2k = bn+r$ with $0 \leq r < n$. From this it follows that
   $$
   x^{2k} = x^{bn+r} = (x^n)^bx^r = (1)^bx^r = x^r=1.
   $$
   This again is a contradiction on the minimality of $n$ as the order of $x$ as the division algorithm requires $r < n$.
   We don't need to consider the case that $2k = n$ because one is even and the other is odd and so can never be equal.

I feel like I've been relying on contradictions a lot working through these basic algebra problems. Is it indicative of a problem? I also feel like I've almost entirely neglected the fact that $n$ is odd, so maybe there is an issue? Or is what I've done a standard approach? (if it's even correct!)

Comment: It should say "$0\leq r<n$" instead of "$0\leq r\leq|n|,$" and "$x^{2k}$" rather than "$x^2k.$" Otherwise, it's fine. You *had* to use the fact that $n$ is odd in the last part.

Comment: Fixed, what were you getting at with the initial comment though?

Comment: I was getting at something I realized you'd already noticed, after re-reading more carefully. Nice work!